# How to draw two curves in a single figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I want to draw the draph of $x^2y=a(x^2+y^2)$ for different values of $a$ on a single figure. How to do that

This is what I have tried.

"This" means obtaining the curves as *level curves* of functions of two variables.

**Remark.** The error probably comes from the fact that the functions `f` and `g` introduced by the user are not defined on the rectangular domain considered.  For example, `g` is not defined if `y=1`.

Anyway, the point of view is not the correct one ; the level curves in general don't answer the initial question.  Only the level curve corresponding to the value *0* is needed.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=1]
        \begin{axis}[axis x line=center, axis y line=center,xmin=-10, ymin=-0.5, xmax=10, ymax=50, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, height=6cm, width=7cm, xlabel style={right}, ylabel style={above}]
            \addplot[id=curve, color=red, smooth, samples=500,raw gnuplot, thick] function{
                f(x,y) = x*x*y-2*(x*x+y*y);
                g(x,y) = x*x*y-(x*x+y*y);
                set xrange [-10:10];
                set yrange [-0.5:50];
                set view 0,0;
                set isosample 1000,1000;
                %set size square;
                set cont base;
                set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
                unset surface;
                splot f(x,y)
            }coordinate[pos=0.5465](B);
            \addplot[id=curve, color=blue, smooth, samples=500,raw gnuplot, thick] function{
                g(x,y) = x*x*y-(x*x+y*y);
                set xrange [-10:10];
                set yrange [-0.5:50];
                set view 0,0;
                set isosample 1000,1000;
                %set size square;
                set cont base;
                set cntrparam levels incre 0,0.1,0;
                unset surface;
                splot g(x,y)
            }coordinate[pos=0.5465](C);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please extend your code into a complete example.  When I do so, I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egTkO.png  What change are you looking for?

Comment: When I do this I get an error

Comment: What is "this"?  Your code needs a documentclass, usepackage, and begin{document} before it can even be understood.  Can you copy and paste the error?

Comment: Like you've been asked for, please extend your code snippet to a [complete WME](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`. And please describe comprehensively your issue and what you need. This way, you would get consistent help.